# Sufficient conditions on a semialgebraic set for being a manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

Let $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ \forall i \in \{1,...,m\}, P_i(x) \geq 0\}$ be a semialgebraic subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for some $n,m \in \mathbb{N}^\ast$).

Are there some sufficient conditions on the $(P_i)_{i =1}^m$ for $A$ being a topological submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ? A differentiable submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: Do you mean a submanifold with boundary?

Comment: Not neccesarily. Initially, I was thinking for example to $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ x+y = 0\}$ (where we don't have any "problem") and $B = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ x^2-y^2 = 0\}$ (where we have a "problem"), but now I need also to consider large inequalities, so that's where my question comes from.

Comment: OK, then you can just use the regular value theorem.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really see the point... With the preceding notation, $B$ is not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is there a general argument, considering a semialgebraic set $X$, to be able to conclude that $X$ is a topological manifold (resp. differentiable manifold) ?

Comment: To get a smooth manifold with corners (a topological submanifold with boundary) it suffices to have linearly independent differentials $dP_i, i\in I$, at every point of simultaneous vanishing of $P_i, i\in I$, for every nonempty subset $I\subset [m]$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.